# Windows 64-bit struct size varies with contained data type?

Tags: c++, struct, sizeof, short

I have two different data structs that should, in principle, have the same size, and I'm wondering why they do not.

```
struct pix1 { 
    unsigned char r; 
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b; 
    unsigned char a; 
    unsigned char y[2]; 
 }; 

struct pix2 { 
    unsigned char r; 
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b; 
    unsigned char a; 
    unsigned short y; 
 };
```

Then, I group four of these pixels together, as such:

```
struct pix4 {
    pix1 pixels[4]; // or pix2 pixels[4]
    unsigned char mask;
};
```

...but it turns out that the size of such a grouping changes, according to sizeof(pix4), depending on whether I use pix1 or pix2.  The individual sizeof(pix1) == sizeof(pix2), so I am confused as to why grouping quartets of pixels changes the size.  I care because it is easier to write programs with the short than with the 2 unsigned chars, but it's costing me 0.25 bytes per pixel.

I'm not sure if this architecture specific, as I haven't tested on other types of machines.  Could it be alignment?  Is this something I need to worry about, or can I proceed with the short implementation?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: #pragma pack(1) to get byte aligned packing (visual studio), then you should get same size in both cases.

Comment: Proper encapsulation would mean you do not care of the exact representation, only of the interface that is being provided. It's easy to have a getter and setter for `y` that take and return a `uint16_t` even if the internal representation is using two individual bytes.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: You're absolutely right.  Getters and setters should abstract away the individual byte access, but since I'm not well-versed in the differences in handling the opposite endian, I'm nervous that I will introduce bugs into the code if I handle endianness incorrectly, that's all.

Comment: @Cindeselia: if you do, then the fix is localized to the getter and setter code, that's only two functions :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size of the structures is the same, but their alignment requirement is different.

Alignment of a structure is the maximum of alignment of all its members. So `pix1` has alignment 1, because it only has chars, but `pix2` has alignment 2 from the short member. The alignment of `pix4` then gets the alignment from the `pixels` member, so it's 1 in the first and 2 in the second case.

Now to ensure all members of an array are properly aligned, size of a structure is rounded up to next multiple of it's alignment. In both cases the size of `pixels` is 24, but then there is 1-byte `mask`. In the first case the alignment is 1, so 25 is multiple of it and `sizeof(pix4)` is 25, but in the second the alignment is 2, so `sizeof(pix4)` has to be rounded up to next even number, 26.

This is the same on all platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it has to do with alignment. The compiler wants to align variables on [natural boundaries](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253665.pdf), hence a short will be 16 bit (2 byte) aligned. And hence the struct which contains a short will also be aligned on a 16 bit boundary.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Err, bit, not byte. Natural boundary == size of the type.

Comment: I have never heard of the term. Mind providing a reference?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: For x86, see e.g. http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253665.pdf

Comment: Well, alignment requirements are always platform-specific, and as the OP asked about Windows 64-bit I assumed he was interested in x86-64 (not that many users of Windows IA-64!). Also, word-aligned does not IMHO describe the full extent of the issue, in that different types have different alignment requirements - wrt the wikipedia article you mention, natural boundary == aligned, "non-natural" boundary == misaligned. Also, if you google for "alignment natural boundary" you'll find that it's used elsewhere as well, e.g. in the documentation for the XLC compiler on AIX/POWER.

Answer (score 1):

The same effect is on Linux 32-bit.

It has to do with padding for alignment reasons.

If you use `struct pix1`, you only have chars and thus `struct pix4` can be left as it is. But if you use `struct pix2`, it contains a short. Thus, the whole struct must be aligned that even in an array of `struct pix4`, every element is aligned for clean access to `y`.

More verbose: A `strict pix4` array with 2 elements would be shaped like this:

```
                +-----     [0]     -----+++-----    [1]     -----+
First version:  rgbayyrgbayyrgbayyrgbayyMrgbayyrgbayyrgbayyrgbayyM
Second version: rgbayyrgbayyrgbayyrgbayyM rgbayyrgbayyrgbayyrgbayyM
                ---------25--------------+ <- +1
```

Why? Because the `---`ed part are 25 bytes, which is an odd number. This is no problem for the first version - the 2nd element can happily start at an odd address - butfor the 2nd version. There the yy must always be on an even (aligned) address, so `struct pix4` is made 26 bytes.

Comment: "must always be on an even (aligned) address" does even mean aligned?

Comment: aligned is a bit more: even is just divisible by 2 - which is enough for `short` - but in the general case (such as of `int64_t` and stuff) - even is not enough. IOW, the term "aligned" is more general.